# To play an asterisk IVR in meetme conference

Tags: asterisk

I would like to play an IVR to menu to every one in the conference
so that any one can select the option menu using DTMF 
can any one tell me how to do this????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task have 2 parts

1) Play message

2) Do dtmf selection in conference.

Task 1 can be archived by create new call

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out

One channel to conference, other to playback your file.

Task 2 depend of your conference app and asterisk version used. For meetme you have option

```
'X' — allow user to exit the conference by entering a valid single digit extension of the context specified in ${MEETME_EXIT_CONTEXT}
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MeetMe